# Extending Length of Air Conditioning Drain Pipe

Tags: plumbing, water, air-conditioning, irrigation

I live in a multi apartment building. All the neighbors has AC.

Many AC's has condensation drainage pipes which descent into the common garden and are cut at about two meters above ground. Others are cut at much higher heights.

I want to extend those low hanging pipes to funnel the water to the trees we have in the garden.

There are two types of pipes. I have attached pictures of both. The pipes are cut in a rough way, no connectors at their ends.

My questions are,

1. How can I extend those pipes? What kind of connectors should I be looking in the store?
2. Can I extend it into a drip irrigation system? Is it possible without adding pressure?

[image: /image/]
[image: /image/]

Comment: Are you apart of the maintenance crew for the apartments?

Comment: @WarLoki In my country almost all multi apartment buildings have a "council" of residents that are responsible for collecting taxes, paying for cleaning, garden, maintenance etc.  Sometimes we/neighbors volunteer to do minor repairs as well.

Comment: look for hose couplers that are "barbed" at both ends. They should have a similar ID as the hoses they connect too.

Comment: if the pipes that drain the condensate are PVC  why not install a PVC hose adapter to lead the water to the tree?

Comment: Or  install a collecting barrel/tank with a spigot at the bottom.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the first picture appears to be dish or clothes washer drain hoses. But to answer your questions: if the hoses are pliable or soft enough any short length of (PVC?) pipe similar to the inside diameter of the hose should suffice as a coupler to join two sections. Secure with hose clamps. Regarding splicing into an irrigation system; if it is not under pressure it might work correctly (or with a check valve installed). Most irrigation systems do function using water from a pressurized line although it is usually reduced by a valve.